# Unable to render a specific view of a object in Open3D

Tags: opencv, graphics, 3d, computer-vision, open3d

I want to render the front view of a 3D object in Open3D/OpenGL after rotating at a specific angle . What parameters should I give in the code below

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import cv2
import copy
mesh_sphere = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere(radius=1.0)
R = mesh.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((np.pi / 2, 0, np.pi / 4))
mesh_r = copy.deepcopy(mesh)
mesh_r.rotate(R, center=(0, 0, 0))
render.scene.set_background([0, 0, 0, 0])
render.scene.add_geometry("model", mesh , mtl)
render.scene.set_lighting(render.scene.LightingProfile.NO_SHADOWS, (0, 0, 0))
  
render.scene.camera.look_at([0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 0, 1]) # what parameters should I give here ?
img_o3d = render.render_to_image()
img = np.array(img_o3d)
  
cv2.imshow("foot_model", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

and the output that I get is the top view of the object , where as I need the front view of the object ( front as in the desktop view that I am able to see) . Please help me to solve this , also if this is not possible through Open3D, links to similar problem solved in OpenGL are also appreciated .

Answer (score 3):

Open3D uses the following (right-handed) axis conventions:

- +X points to the right
- +Y points up
- +Z points out of the screen

In your example, the camera is positioned at Y=10, which is above the target, looking down. To look from the front, into the screen, all that is needed is for the Y and Z values to be switched around.

So `look_at([0, 0, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 0, 1])` becomes `look_at([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 0])`.

Here is a commented, working example using Open3D 0.12.0:

```py
# To install dependencies: pip install numpy, open3d, opencv-python
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import cv2
import copy

# Create a renderer with the desired image size
img_width = 640
img_height = 480
render = o3d.visualization.rendering.OffscreenRenderer(img_width, img_height)

# Pick a background colour (default is light gray)
render.scene.set_background([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.0])  # RGBA

# Create the mesh geometry.
# (We use arrows instead of a sphere, to show the rotation more clearly.)
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(size=1.0, origin=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]))

# Create a copy of the above mesh and rotate it around the origin.
# (If the original mesh is not going to be used, we can just rotate it directly without making a copy.)
R = mesh.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((np.pi / 2, 0, np.pi / 4))
mesh_r = copy.deepcopy(mesh)
mesh_r.rotate(R, center=(0, 0, 0))

# Show the original coordinate axes for comparison.
# X is red, Y is green and Z is blue.
render.scene.show_axes(True)

# Define a simple unlit Material.
# (The base color does not replace the arrows' own colors.)
mtl = o3d.visualization.rendering.Material()  # or MaterialRecord(), for later versions of Open3D
mtl.base_color = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]  # RGBA
mtl.shader = "defaultUnlit"

# Add the arrow mesh to the scene.
# (These are thicker than the main axis arrows, but the same length.)
render.scene.add_geometry("rotated_model", mesh_r, mtl)

# Since the arrow material is unlit, it is not necessary to change the scene lighting.
#render.scene.scene.enable_sun_light(False)
#render.scene.set_lighting(render.scene.LightingProfile.NO_SHADOWS, (0, 0, 0))

# Optionally set the camera field of view (to zoom in a bit)
vertical_field_of_view = 15.0  # between 5 and 90 degrees
aspect_ratio = img_width / img_height  # azimuth over elevation
near_plane = 0.1
far_plane = 50.0
fov_type = o3d.visualization.rendering.Camera.FovType.Vertical
render.scene.camera.set_projection(vertical_field_of_view, aspect_ratio, near_plane, far_plane, fov_type)

# Look at the origin from the front (along the -Z direction, into the screen), with Y as Up.
center = [0, 0, 0]  # look_at target
eye = [0, 0, 10]  # camera position
up = [0, 1, 0]  # camera orientation
render.scene.camera.look_at(center, eye, up)

# Read the image into a variable
img_o3d = render.render_to_image()

# Display the image in a separate window
# (Note: OpenCV expects the color in BGR format, so swop red and blue.)
img_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img_o3d), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA)
cv2.imshow("Preview window", img_cv2)
cv2.waitKey()

# Optionally write it to a PNG file
o3d.io.write_image("output.png", img_o3d, 9)
```

Result:

[image: output.png]

The thin lines are the unrotated axes, where Up = +Y = green and Right = +X = red.

Comment: Using Open3D in interactive mode could also be helpful, just to get a more intuitive feel for the rotations. Pressing `P` in that mode will automatically save the current camera parameters to a JSON file.

Comment: To make the camera follow the model as it rotates, instead of always standing still in the front, all you have to do is to apply that same rotation matrix to the camera (both its position and its up vector.)

Comment: I actually got the convention upside down, according to this Open3D issue:
https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/issues/1347

The rotations are right-handed either way, so the example code still works. Just take note of the direction of the arrows.

Comment: This was literally the best. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried rendering a scene using above code but the rendered scene is all black. I have used ```o3d.visualization.rendering.MaterialRecord()``` instead of Material() because Material() is depreciated in recent version of Open3D